# Use object :title in URL routes rather than :id

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

***Update:** please see my answer below for final solution*

I have an object with unique title names and I'd like to utilise the titles rather than the ID's throughout the website in routes.

**routes.js**

```
// Current routing

var articles = require('../app/controllers/articles')

app.param('articleId', articles.load)
app.get('/articles', articles.index)
app.get('/articles/new', articles.new)
app.post('/articles', articles.create)
app.get('/articles/:articleId', articles.show)
app.get('/articles/:articleId/edit', articles.edit)
app.put('/articles/:articleId', articles.update)
app.del('/articles/:articleId', articles.destroy)

***

// Desired routing

app.param('articleTitle', articles.load)
app.get('/articles', articles.index)
app.get('/articles/new', articles.new)
app.post('/articles', articles.create)
app.get('/articles/:articleTitle', articles.show)
app.get('/articles/:articleTitle/edit', articles.edit)
app.put('/articles/:articleTitle', articles.update)
app.del('/articles/:articleTitle', articles.destroy)
```

**articles.js (Controller)**

```
exports.load = function(req, res, next, title){
  Article.load(title, function (err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!article) return next(new Error('not found'))
    req.article = article
    next()
  })
}

exports.show = function(req, res){
  res.render('articles/show', {
    title: req.article.title,
    article: req.article
  })
}
```

**article.js (Model)**

```
ArticleSchema.statics = {
  load: function (title, cb) {
    this.findOne({ title : title })
      .exec(cb)
  }
}
```

Basically, I've subbed out any id references and replaced them with title references. For some reason they simply are not working.

An example would be going to a URL `http://localhost:3000/articles/test` rather than `http://localhost:3000/articles/5TheId234`, which doesn't work, throwing this error: GET /articles/test 404 148ms

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain that there is a `article` document in your mongo database with title set to `test`? I suspect that this is the issue: `Article.load` does not find any document and does not call `next()` which causes 404 error.

Comment: You were correct, it was the data after all. It was an old record using an old fieldname for title (mongodb) so it didn't have a title until I updated it! I've added a little extra function as a response to my own question which includes a new 'url' field, rather than title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it was just a copy and paste error when you posted this question, but I noticed that your new route has a typo (it should be articles.new):

```
app.get('/articles/new', rticles.new)
```

I wondered whether it wasn't perhaps the ordering of the routes that would cause some routes to override others. But I created a simple test and it seems to be working fine.

As you can see the following tests the same routes you have and it works exactly as expected. Fire this up and have a look? Maybe this can narrow down the issue for you.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var articles = [
    {id: 1, title: 'tagtreetv_rocks', 
        link: 'http://localhost:3000/articles/tagtreetv_rocks'
    },
    {id: 2, title: 'tagtreetv_launches', 
        link: 'http://localhost:3000/articles/tagtreetv_launches'
    }
];


app.param('articleTitle', function(req, res, next, title){
    var article = articles.filter(function(a){return a.title == title;});   
    if (!article) return next(new Error('not found'));
    req.article = article;
    next();
});

app.get('/articles/new', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        id: '?',
        title: '?'
    });
});

app.get('/articles', function(req, res){
    res.json(articles); 
});

app.post('/articles', function(req, res){
    articles.push(req.body);
    res.send(200);
});

app.get('/articles/:articleTitle', function(req, res){
    res.json(req.article);
});

app.get('/articles/:articleTitle/edit', function(req, res){
    res.json(req.article);
});



app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Btw, if you are interested in full stack JavaScript programming, I've recently launched some screencasts on the topic: http://tagtree.tv!

Comment: Ah, it was a copy and paste error, I fixed it up. So guess what, it was the data after all. It was an old record using an old fieldname for title (mongodb) so it didn't have a title until I updated it! As for your website, it looks really good mate, hopefully I can watch some of them at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It was a data error, but I've improved on my initial structure by creating and utilizing a separate url field based off the input title:

**routes.js**

```
var articles = require('../app/controllers/articles')

app.param('articleURL', articles.load)
app.get('/articles', articles.index)
app.get('/articles/new', articles.new)
app.post('/articles', articles.create)
app.get('/articles/:articleURL', articles.show)
app.get('/articles/:articleURL/edit', articles.edit)
app.put('/articles/:articleURL', articles.update)
app.del('/articles/:articleURL', articles.destroy)
```

**articles.js (Controller)**

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body)

  // Builds URL by removing spaces
  // note: url is a hidden field in the form
  // replaces spaces with underscores
  // removes all special characters (not '_')
  // converts to lowercase
  // to shorten the length, use 'substring(0,18)' - 18 char max example
  article.url = sport.title.replace(/ /g,'_').replace(/\W/g,'').toLowerCase() 

  article.uploadAndSave(req.files.image, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      req.flash('success', 'Successfully created article!')
      return res.redirect('/article/'+article.url)
    }
    res.render('articles/new', {
      title: 'New Article',
      sport: article,
      errors: utils.errors(err.errors || err)
    })
  })
}

exports.load = function(req, res, next, title){
  Article.load(title, function (err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!article) return next(new Error('not found'))
    req.article = article
    next()
  })
}

exports.show = function(req, res){
  res.render('articles/show', {
    title: req.article.title,
    article: req.article
  })
}
```

**article.js (Model)**

```
ArticleSchema.statics = {
  load: function (url, cb) {
    this.findOne({ url : url })
      .exec(cb)
  }
}
```